# quarkus opentelemetry kuberbetes pod name

Tags: java, kubernetes, quarkus, open-telemetry

We are on Quarkus 2.13.x and are using the opentelemetry libraries to implement telemetry with some automatic and manual context propagation. It's working fine so far but i recently noticed one of the missing info. We have some microservices with multiple replicas so we have more than 1 kubernetes pod running per service. When we get the telemetry information, it is not evident on which pod the request is being serviced by. Is it possible to add this information to the telemetry trace/span metadata?

Thank you
SG

Comment: 2.13 is pretty old now. Does the same behavior occur with the latest versions?

Answer (score 1):

That information is not currently gathered.
The `HOSTNAME` env. var. should include the ID but we are only including the IP. Will submit an enhancement for future versions.

On the old Quarkus 2.16 you can expose the `metadata.name` field from the manifest as an env. var. and then use it through the resources property: `quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.resource-attributes=host.name=${METADATA_NAME}`

You can also evaluate options like this in the quarkus-kubernetes extension.
https://quarkus.io/version/2.16/guides/deploying-to-kubernetes#environment-variables-from-fields

Comment: Thank you very much! HOSTNAME has the data required.

Comment: @sg1973 I created this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/36968
In the future the hostame will be sent for all spans.